# finding the constant $c$ in the density

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I want to find $c$ from the density function $f(x)=c/x^4$ for $0<\theta\le x<\infty$

All I need help with is setting up the bounds for the integral to set equal to 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The upper bound is $+\infty$. The lower bound is $\theta$ (a variable, so that $c$ depends on $\theta$).